# Error using solvePnPRansac function

Tags: python, opencv, estimation

I'm using Python 2.7 and opencv 3.0.0.
I'm trying to do a pose estimation on a live video.
So i used the calibrate.py gave by opencv. it works good.
In this program, I added at the end lines to treat the informations in order to pose axis. I used this : http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d53/tutorial_py_pose.html#gsc.tab=0

On the line with solvePnPRansac function I wrote this instead : `_, rvecs, tvecs, inliers = cv2.solvePnPRansac(obj_points[0], corners2, camera_matrix, dist_coefs)` adding the `_,`at the beginning of the line.

I have this error appearing !

```
error: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win64-vc12-static\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:2294: error: (-215) d == 2 && (sizes[0] == 1 || sizes[1] == 1 || sizes[0]*sizes[1] == 0) in function cv::_OutputArray::create
```

I don't understand it at all !

Can someone help me ?

Here is my code to treat the video :

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):


    # Take each frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (6,5),None)

    if ret:

        term = ( cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 30, 0.1 )

        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),term)


        _, rvecs, tvecs, inliers = cv2.solvePnPRansac(obj_points[0], corners2, camera_matrix, dist_coefs)

        imgpts, jac = cv2.projectPoints(axis, rvecs, tvecs, camera_matrix, dist_coefs)


        frame = draw(frame,corners2,imgpts)

    cv2.imshow('img',frame)

    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: same here, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. 
I used solvePnP instead of solvePnPRansac and it worked fine.
I guess solvePnPRansac in python has a bug.

Answer (score 0):

[solvePnpRansac](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga50620f0e26e02caa2e9adc07b5fbf24e&gsc.tab=0) has only three output values:

```
OutputArray     rvec,
OutputArray     tvec, 
OutputArray     inliers = noArray(),
```

so removing the `_,` in the beginning should make the program work again.

Comment: That didn't work for me. I get:     rvec, tvec, inliers = cv2.solvePnPRansac(objp, corners2, K, D)
cv2.error: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win64-vc12-static\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:2355: error: (-215) d == 2 && (sizes[0] == 1 || sizes[1] == 1 || sizes[0]*sizes[1] == 0) in function cv::_OutputArray::create

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `obj_points` the same manner in the example.
I don't see `obj_points` definition in the provided code snippet and I think that's the issue

```
obj_points= np.zeros((6*7,3), np.float32)
obj_points[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in the 3D model point definition between solvePnP and solvePnPRansac. [Is not clear in the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#solvepnpransac), but solvePnP needs the model defined with a matrix with dimensions 3xN/Nx3 and solvePnPRansac needs the model with a matrix with dimensions 3x1xN/Nx1x3.

You can use this code to include the extra dimension to your model:

```
modelNx1x3 = np.zeros((N, 1, 3), np.float32)
modelNx1x3[:, 0, :] = modelNx3[:, :]
```

You can also find further details in [the issue tracker in github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6304)